# Android: value of one spinner depends on value of other spinner

Tags: android, database, spinner, adapter

I have a problem on Android Spinner.In my application I created two Spinner on main layout. 'State' Spinner and 'District' Spinner. All the data on Spinner are stored in SQLite database. I want do display list of 'District' on second spinner depending on selection of particular 'State' in the first spinner.
Example: Suppose when I select Karnataka in the first spinner then application first retrieve all the district from SQLite database related to karnataka state and then it display on second Spinner.

For this I do all the database activity correctly means creating two table 'state' and 'district' in which one column in district table is foreign key which is refereed to one of the primary key of 'state table'

```
db.execSQL("create table "+STATE_TABLE+" ("+
            STATE_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement not null, "+
                STATE_NAME+" text"+")");

    db.execSQL("create table "+DISTRICT_TABLE+" ("+DISTRICT_ID+
            " integer primary key autoincrement not null,"+DISTRICT_NAME
                +" text,"+STATE_ID+" integer, FOREIGN KEY("
                    +STATE_ID+") REFERENCES "+STATE_TABLE
                        +"("+STATE_ID+")"+")");
```

Now in the Activity Class:

```
spinnerState = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinnerDistrict = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
stateList = new ArrayList<String>();
districtList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Suppose all the data are all ready stored in database.**

Now I need to retrieve all the 'State' data from database and add it in the statelist which is ArrayList.

```
Cursor stateCursor = database.query(STATE_TABLE, new String[]{STATE_ID, STATE_NAME},
            null, null, null, null, STATE_NAME);
    stateCursor.moveToFirst();

    if(! stateCursor.isAfterLast()){
        do{
            int id = stateCursor.getInt(0);
            String stateName = stateCursor.getString(1);
            stateList.add(stateName);
        }while(stateCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    stateCursor.close();
```

after this I create one ArrayAdapter and put this state list into this.

```
spinnerState.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stateList));
```

Next i put the following code in the activity class:

```
spinnerState.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int pos, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

**Now My problem is here:**

1. How I get the StateId for executing the select query for taking all the district related to particular state in database.
2. How the adapter will generate for District.
3. where I put all these code.

Here what I need creating the districtList after getting the value from state Spinner.

Similar Question which asked earlier in this website, what they do:
they already create two adapter for two spinner and then apply setOnItemSelectedListener. 
Please Help me because here my mind totally stop working.
I refer lot of book and website but not they even mention these type of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of solutions here:

### Option 1:

Instead of declaring `stateList` as an `ArrayList<String>`, create a custom POJO `StateInfo` and designate stateList as `ArrayList<StateInfo>`

```
public class StateList {
    private int id;
    private String stateName;

    //Constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Then,

```
if(! stateCursor.isAfterLast()){
    do{
        int id = stateCursor.getInt(0);
        String stateName = stateCursor.getString(1);
        stateList.add(new StateInfo(id, stateName));
    }while(stateCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Now, you can do this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
        int pos, long id) {
    int id = stateList.get(pos).getId();
    //Use This ID to construct your next SQLite query; and populate the district spinner.
}
```

If you do this, you will have to create a custom `ArrayAdapter` and implement the `getView()` method. Look at the Android docs for how to do this.

### Option 2:

Why do you even need the stateID? I suppose you can write a Query to get the districts list given a state Name only. In that case, you can retain the `stateList` as an `ArrayList<String>` and you don't even need the `StateInfo` class at all. Just do this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
        int pos, long id) {
    String stateName = stateList.get(pos);
    //Use this name to construct your next SQLite query; and populate the district spinner.
}
```

Comment: Plus, since the list of districts for a state will not change during the execution of the program; you can preload a `HahMap` of `<stateName, districtList>` (one for each state) asynchronously at the program startup; or at least cache the values on first fetch. If you do this, you do not need to do additional queries when one state is selected; you can directly look into `HashMap` in `onItemSelected()`.

Comment: thank you for quick response.
but I am not able to write code for second spinner which show district.
so please specify me full code for district spinner.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Are you able to write the query? Does it return the cursor for districts as expected? Please be more detailed so that we can help you.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? If any of the answers here helped you, you should upvote or accept it. If not, then it is a good practice to share your solution here :)

Answer (score 1):

**For problem 1:**

You just need to keep track of which state user selects into the spinner and according to its position,you have to find its related id.then you can query for district accordingly.obviously you will have to use onItemSelectedListener of that spinner to get position of state selected.

**For problem 2:**

You need to make a method in helper class which accepts stateId(which you would compute as i said above) and return you according district names in a String array.So in your main activity,in onItemSelectedListener of a state spinner,you will have to grab that string array and prepare a adapter for the same. There,you will have to set adapter to your district spinner.

This will always give you your district spinner updated with what user selects in state array.

**For problem 3:**

Almost all code would be in onItemSelectedListener of your state spinner only.Just a method to fetch related district names would be in your helper class.